# Dinky cars (toy cars)

Tags: word-choice, british-english, north-american-english, south-african-english, antipodean-english

I came across this term while proofreading an unpublished poem by an Irish poet. The context is not important so I'll just say that it is clear that it means “toy cars”.

I [Googled the term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinky_Toys) and see that it refers to a brand-name of die-cast toy car made by the British company Meccano starting in 1931, but, as far as I can tell, petering out in the early 1970s.

Is this a term that’s generally recognized, today, on both sides of the Atlantic? If I said “that’s a *dinky car*” in the US to an 18-year-old, would they understand? Or would the term only be understood by an older person (I’m Canadian and in my 40s, so I'm guessing older than me)? Would it only be understood in the UK/Ireland (/Australia, New Zealand, South Africa, etc.)?

In other words:

1. Is the term recognizable to a younger person? If so, in which countries?
2. Is the term recognizable to a North American? If so, of what ages?

And finally:

3. Is there a term for a toy car (other than *toy car*) that *is* widely recognized by English speakers of different ages and from different countries?

Comment: These are often referred to as *Dinky toys*, since the firm made models of many things besides cars.

Comment: You mean there was a company that actually named itself *Dinky*? Deliberately? Let's just say, I'm not surprised we're talking about it in the past tense. :)

Comment: @Marthaª No, Dinky cars were made by Meccano (part of Hornby). Matchbox cars were made by Lesney. Both are now owned by Mattel.

Comment: In most countries, when a brand name becomes the standard term for a category of product, it is said to become *generic* and it loses its protection as a trademark. In the US, this is the case with *elevator*, but not with *Kleenex*.

Comment: @bib I think Kleenex is going that way, though.  I (and many in the area I grew up) learned to use "kleenex" for all types of tissues.  Ten years later, "tissue" still sounds odd to me.

Comment: @Izkata - Kimberley-Clark will fight you to the death on that one (or at least try and make your life very litigious and unpleasant)(See comment on FumbleFingers answer). If you just whisper it to your friends, you may be safe.

Comment: I was born in 88’ and grew up here in Nova Scotia calling any small toy car Dinkys, as did my parents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although *dinky* is defined as "small; insignificant", as a North American speaker, I would think of a small, *full-sized* vehicle, like a VW Beetle or a Mini Cooper. A **Matchbox car** would be recognizable, though collectors might find it too specific if you're referring to die-cast toy cars, in general.

**Edit:** Some people may take issue with the use of a trademark as a generic term (which I would liken to [frisbee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_disc)), and although the company has its roots in the UK, it may not be well-known there. If you are wanting to avoid the word "toy", then perhaps simply **die-cast car** would work.

Comment: So you're saying a North American, without context, might understand "dinky car" to mean a small car. I wonder if "Matchbox car" (which I have heard) is understood in Ireland/UK?

Comment: @JAM I would think so since the [company began in the UK](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-467341/The-man-boyish-Matchbox-toy-actually-DAUGHTER.html), but only a native/resident could say for sure. (And yes, a "dinky car" might be understood as a "small car" or (mis)-understood as a shoddy "*rinky-dink*" car) :)

Comment: As a North American from central New Jersey, I most associate the term "Dinky car" with the [Princeton Branch train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princeton_Branch).  Next I'd think of a small car.  I'd never get to a model car.

Comment: @Zairja great link +1

Comment: @Charles useful context

Comment: Like @Charles & Zairja, I'd think of a small car before a toy car, but I'd like to add, I'd probably think of a Yugo before a Mini Cooper. (_Dinky_ has almost an inherently pejorative ring to it; in the U.S., _rinky-dink_ means "something considered shoddy and inferior.")

Comment: But [Matchbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matchbox_(brand)) is just another brand name the same as Dinky.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's correct. The only difference is that I believe a *Matchbox™* car could be used in a generic sense, since it's widely known, similar to *frisbee*.

Comment: @Zairja: Maybe US/UK usage differs on that one. In the UK, just about any small model can be called "dinky" (anything small, in fact, not just "scale models"). But "matchbox" is only meaningful to those who know the brand-name, or who can guess the sense by knowing that matchboxes are inherently small.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for the input from someone who lives there, which is what JAM was looking for. I had updated my answer, but I'm not sure how to improve it further for the downvoter(s), since other than our two suggestions I cannot think of a simple alternative to *toy car* (in the context of the poem).

Comment: In my part of the USA, anything smaller than a truck would qualify as a "dinky car". We do love our big iron boxes...

Comment: I think of both Matchbox and Hot Wheels as a specific type of toy car, not generic.  For generic usage, I say 'toy car'.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek: You're obviously not closely connected with (adult) people who own such things. I'm not a fanatic/collector, but for quirky reasons I happen to own some very valuable diecast scale-model model buses. They are not "toys" (several are worth £100s, if not $1000s). I know nothing of "Hot Wheels", but a rare quality model produced by *any* manufacturer may be valuable. As a one-time supplier to UK bus companies, I often accepted a lower contract price in return for a "limited-edition" model in the customer's livery.

Answer (score 7):

In the US, *dinky* would be recognized to [mean](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/dinky)

> Of small size or consequence; insignificant.

It would not be understood to refer to a *toy car* by either an 18 year old or a 65 year old.

*Matchbox* has been offered as an alternative, but that is a trademark for a specific brand of toy car.

*Scale model car* has also been suggested, and that is used in the US, as well as the shortened version *model car*.  However *model car* was, up until several years ago, primarily used to refer to plastic *models* that were sold in pieces to be assembled with glue and often painted by the purchaser.

Comment: What 'e said, folks. *Dinky* is not a nice thing to say about someone's car, and never in a million years would the words "dinky car" bring to mind a cast-iron toy car.

Comment: @Marthaª - but there are probably a few owners of Mini Coopers and VW Bugs who just *might* buy into the term *dinky*.

Comment: Perhaps we have stumbled upon a difference in connotation between N. Am. and Brit. I am British. If someone called my small car 'dinky', it would be with an enthusiastic voice, and I would be happy to receive the compliment.

Comment: If you use the term "dinky" in Minnesota folks are apt to think you're referring to [Dinkytown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinkytown).

Answer (score 5):

As a Canadian (from BC) in my mid-30's, I recall my mom using this term (dinky car) when I was growing up. I didn't even consider that it might not be universal until reading your question just now.

I'd say that I agree that the only other term besides simply "toy car" or "dinky car" that I've heard would be a matchbox car.

Comment: I'm Canadian, from Ontario, and in late 20's, and dinky cars is what I called them when I was a kid.

Comment: @Grant, your comment seems to go against what most other North Americans have said about the term "dinky," (myself included). I'm curious -- did you have British (or Irish) parents or grandparents? I only ask because I'm trying to sort out the 'universality' of the term "dinky car."

Comment: My ancestry is quite mixed, but at least back to my grandparents they were raised in Canada.  And it wasn't just my family - it was a common term with other children as far as I remember.  It probably wasn't the most common term (which was likely Hot Wheels), but it was used frequently.

Comment: My ancestry is similar to @Grant, including that my grandparents (on my mother's side) were from Ontario. I believe my great-grandparents were immigrants from the UK, but that is long enough ago to pre-date the dinky car as a term.

Perhaps the term was in heavier use in Ontario for a time compared to elsewhere?

Answer (score 4):

I grew up in the UK (b. 1961). We had Dinky cars. We also had Matchbox cars, which were slightly smaller. Dinky cars later became quite collectable, but for that, they'd need to be pretty much un-played-with. In any case, the name is quite recognisable to me.

Comment: Brits of a certain age know what we're on about.  I'd say "dinky" means small/cute and I agree with @Barry Brown above.

Answer (score 3):

[Dinky (dinkey)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dinky) goes back to 1788 *from Scottish dialectal dink "finely dressed, trim"*, so obviously the trademark usage came later.

Thus it's *not* the same as, for example, [Brits] using **hoover** as a generic word for a vacuum cleaner, even though many people might think of **Dinky** that way (or indeed, [Matchbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matchbox_%28brand%29) or [Hot-Wheels](http://www.toysrus.co.uk/browse/product/hot-wheels), other related proprietary usages).

A more generic term would be **[scale-]model car**. Note that some serious collectors would object to calling such things "toys". They're also sometimes called [diecast models](http://www.modelzone.co.uk/diecast-models.html), which invariably implies "dimensionally accurate, small-scale" reproductions.

Comment: It's almost a crapshoot which trademarks get genericized on which side of the pond. :) Matchbox car is definitely as generic as frisbee or kleenex in the US, but Hoover is a brand name and hardly ever a generic.

Comment: @Mark Beadles: I didn't know until I just looked it up, but apparently Hoover was [originally an *American* company](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hoover_Company). But Wikipedia says there the "eponymous" usage for vacuum cleaners in general is primarily British/Irish, which agrees with what you say.

Comment: While commonly used (incorrectly according to the corporate owners), [FRISBEE](http://tess2.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4006:eai7du.3.53), [KLEENEX](http://tess2.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4006:eai7du.5.32) and [HOOVER](http://tess2.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4006:eai7du.6.64) are all valid trademarks in the US and are not considered generic (which would mean they lost legal protection). No enforcement is taken against individuals in everyday speech, but if there were commercial use of these terms by anyone other than the owners, the lawyers would weigh in.

Comment: @bib: Hmm. Maybe in your universe, big money tells you what word you can and can't use. In my universe, ***I*** decide what words I will use. If I walk into a cafe and and for "a Coke" (capitalised or not, the guy behind the counter can't hear the difference), I don't give a toss whether the cola I drink is made by Pepsi-Cola, Coca-Cola, or Cheaper-But-Just-As-Good-Cola. And where ***I*** live, Coca-Cola wouldn't have a hope in hell of prosecuting me for misusing their supposedly copyright word "coke".

Comment: You are right about Coca-Cola not planning to prosecute you, but if they did, it would be for trademark infringement not copyright. And if they did, guys like me would defend you.

Comment: @bib: Ty for the offer, but I would be fine. (As they say around these parts, *"I ain't frit!" :)*

Comment: @FumbleFingers; only just seen this, but maybe one more comment is still on-topic.  *You* would never be in danger of prosecution, but it *is* possible for the barman to be sued ('passing off') for giving you a generic cola rather than a genuine one; Coca-Cola hope to intimidate him into asking "Do you want a real Coke or a cheaper Bubbli-Cola, sir?" and the fact that your  reply was "I really don't give a fizz" would be relevant evidence, but not decisive. (Yes, I have listened incredulously to such trials, involving *inter alia* chocolate biscuits and vodka.)

Answer (score 3):

I grew up mostly in the United States, with brief childhood sojourns on U.S. naval bases in the Western Pacific. I bought die-cast cars from about the third grade on, and had never heard of the Dinky brand. Given that background, here are my answers:

1. Given that Meccano (Dinky) [went belly-up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die-cast_toy) in the 1980s, I would suspect that only someone who had been a small boy (or girl) in 1980s, and living in the UK, would have heard of Dinky. Anyone younger than that would have had to have had a relative who was an ardent collector of die-cast cars.
2. This North American had never heard of Dinky until now, and I graduated from college in the mid-1980s.
3. Speaking from personal experience with friends and relatives living in Europe, Asia, and Australia, I'd say that *Hot Wheels* would currently be the most recognizable term for "die-cast toy car" around the world, and probably the closest to being a generic term. (The "Choose Country" pull-down on the Hot Wheels [web site](http://www.hotwheels.com/)
   lists 22 countries, including 4 English-speaking ones.)

When I bought a (real) MINI Cooper 5 years ago, I mentioned the fact to a nephew who was living in Singapore, who replied, "Oh, yeah -- I have a Hot Wheels of the Cooper S."

Answer (score 2):

Old topic, but thought I'd chime in.  I'm a late-30s Canadian from the east coast.  I have a collection of about 300 toy cars that I received when I was a kid.  I call them my Dinky collection even though there isn't a Dinky Toy among them.  All Hot Wheels and Matchbox.

Comment: Three new "Dinky" cars in my son's collection as of today...

Comment: I actually had a conversation about Dinkys tonight and thought I'd Google it and this page came up.  I'm surprised that no one else has mentioned another meaning/use of dinky.  ie: a penis.  When I was a kid Dinky was just what we called these cars.  At the time I just assumed they were called this because they are somewhat penis-sized.

Comment: hilarious! Yes I too wondered why the other meaning hadn't come up yet.

Answer (score 1):

Usual 'sample size of one' disclaimer, but over on this side of the pond (Australia) in my social group (30ish) I suspect we'd understand dinky as an adjective to mean toy-like (shorthand for small, cute, dainty, etc).

Quoting from the Macquarie Encyclopedic Dictionary (1990 ed):

> **dinky** (adj.). **dinkier**, **dinkiest**, *n. pl.* **dinkies**. *Colloq, -adj.*
>
> 1. of small size.
> 2. neat; dainty; smart.
> 3. a small tricycle
> 4. dinghy [from a British dialect]

One note I'd add to the Macquarie - it's not something you'd hear in a positive sense in my group - you'd be likely to hear dinky applied in a way that's less complimentary and more belittling to the object/owner. Example being to call someone's car dinky would generally mean you're saying that it's small (and not large, and spacious), and rather dainty (and not muscular or suited to the rigors of real world usage), so in that sense we'd be close to the AmE answer from @BiB.

Speculating, I'd guess that the negativity came about because of the demise of the Dinky. We retained the word and its essential core to denote something as a toy but instead of drawing from a positive comparison to a finely crafted work of art (lacking actual contact with a Dinky) we can only draw on the other idea of calling something a toy when it's not intended to be a toy - that's almost never positive.

Comment: Interesting -- thanks for the Australian perspective. Seems that Brits and Canadians are more familiar with 'Dinky cars' as a term, than Americans and Australians (apply your disclaimer here re small sample size). I myself wasn't familiar with the term despite an English mother, but that might be because my gender didn't tend to get given toy cars when I was growing up!

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Pakistan and I called all small toy cars 'dinky cars' when I was growing up - just like Americans call tissue Kleenex, or Xerox for photo copies, etc. I'm not sure whether I even owned any Dinky cars, of the brand, but it was just what you called them! Having read the above comments, where dinky cars are predominantly known as such in Britain, then I guess this could be part of the imperial hangover as well!

Answer (score -1):

I was born in 1961 on the Jersey Shore. As I kid, I had a great collection of Dinky's. We would play with them for hours in our backyard under the tree in the dirt. We would make parking lots out of mud and park the Dinkys. That's what we always called them all. As I grew older and talked about my fond memories with playing with the Dinkys, no one seemed to know what they were. Then I went to a toy museum and saw a huge collection of Dinkys like the ones I used to play with. I wish I kept them! Brought back great memories! I even saw an old doll I used to play with called Miss Peep. (I still have mine but its leg is broken and pinned back to the torso). Yes, I am a female but was a Tomboy back in the day and loved those Dinkys. Now does anyone remember Miss Peep?